# How do I initialize a list of string arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I've looked around but can't find my answer.

I have this code:

```
List<String[]> _myList = new List<String[]>();
```

I just want to initialize it with values but I don't know how. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
List<String[]> _myList = new List<String[]>()
        {
            new string[] { "string", "more string" },
            new string[] { "and more string"},
        };
```

or add after initialization like this:

```
_myList.Add(new string[] {"add more string"});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
List<String[]> _myList = new List<String[]>{new String[]{"a","b"},new String[]{"c","d"}};
```

This is the `List Initializer` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
List<String[]> _myList = new List<String[]> { new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d"}, 
                                              new String[] { "a", "b"},
                                              new String[] { "b", "c"} };
```

This is the *collection initializer* syntax. For more information about this, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string[]> _myList = new List<string[]>() { new string[1] { "Cool" }, new string[2] { "Also", "cool" } };
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, a  List is not an array in that a list can have a variable number of items in it; on the other hand, an array has a fixed number of items or members which must be declared and adhered to.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

Class Program



   {
        Static Void Main(string[] args)
        Var names = new List<string>
        {
             "Dave",
             "Steve",
             "Joe",
        };
   // you can get additional names added by using the Add keyword


       names.Add("Hillary")

     // If you want to print your list you can use the foreach loop 
       foreach(string name in names)
       Console.Writeline(names);
```

}